# Ensure input escaping in JSP

Tags: xss, java

All user input should be [escaped](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).
But unfortunately when using JSP we have to do this exlicitly by using 
Often unexperienced developers just use ${value}, which just writes the value without escaping.

Is it possible to escape all values which are written by ${value} per default?

Otherwise, is there a static code analysis tool which finds uses of ${value} without c:out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All user-supplied input should be validated on entry (use Hibernate Validator with its @SafeHtml annotation), so you don't fill your database with potential XSS that could wreck another application, or later versions of the same application

You could use my crude tool to validate all GET & POST parameters and header names and values:

http://blog.databasepatterns.com/2015/08/simple-inbound-xss-filter-for-spring.html

Heads up: it doesn't validate request bodies

User-supplied data should be escaped on output as well

You can use this Expression Language resolver to "auto" escape all JSP pages https://pukkaone.github.io/2011/01/03/jsp-cross-site-scripting-elresolver.html

Comment: The second solution answers my question. But you're right: Validation is even better. Thanks!